# Navigation Bar BackButton doesn't work perfectly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, ibaction

I have a "FairListViewController". This is the first ViewController. Here by touching a tableCell, I can go to next which is "MenuViewController". And there are two Button, "Product" for "ProductViewController" and "Events" for "EventViewController". I use "NavigationController" as a "rootViewController" in my appDelegate. Now when i touch "Product" button in "MenuViewController" in takes me to "ProductViewController" and touching "BackButton" it smoothly back to "MenuViewController". I did the same code for "ProductViewController", here it takes me to the "EventViewController" but after touching "BackButton", strangely it takes back to First Page which is "FairListViewController". I change the name of my IBAction Button name ( In "EventViewController" nib file) several times & reconnect with nib file, even delete the button from nib file and try with a new button, but the result is same! Can any one similar to this problem before. Any suggestion will be highly appreciable. Thanks a lot in Advance.

**Here is my code :**

IN MenuViewController (For ProductViewController Button):

```
- (IBAction)callProductGroups:(id)sender
{
ProductGroupViewController *productGroupViewController;

if(IS_IPHONE_5)
{
    productGroupViewController = [[ProductGroupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductGroupViewController" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
    productGroupViewController = [[ProductGroupViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProductGroupViewControlleriPhone4" bundle:nil];
}

productGroupViewController.topBarImageForAll = self.topBarImageForAll;
productGroupViewController.topBarButtonImageForAll = self.topBarButtonImageForAll;
productGroupViewController.buttonDividerImageForAll = self.buttonDividerImageForAll;
productGroupViewController.backgroundImageForAll = self.backgroundImageForAll;
productGroupViewController.backgroundImageiPhone4ForAll = self.backgroundImageiPhone4ForAll;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:productGroupViewController animated:YES];
}
```

**In ProductViewController :**

```
-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**In MenuViewController (For EventViewController Button):**

```
- (IBAction)callEvents:(id)sender
{
EventViewController *eventViewController;

if (IS_IPHONE_5)
{
    eventViewController=[[EventViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EventViewController" bundle:nil];
}
else
{
    eventViewController=[[EventViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EventViewControlleriPhone4" bundle:nil];
}

eventViewController.topBarImageForAll = self.topBarImageForAll;
eventViewController.topBarButtonImageForAll = self.topBarButtonImageForAll;
eventViewController.buttonDividerImageForAll = self.buttonDividerImageForAll;
eventViewController.backgroundImageForAll = self.backgroundImageForAll;
eventViewController.backgroundImageiPhone4ForAll = self.backgroundImageiPhone4ForAll;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:eventViewController animated:YES];    
}
```

**In EvenViewController :**

```
- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

[There is no problem of Going to next ViewController, the problem is about Coming Back.]

Comment: Because you are sending `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:`.

Comment: But i sending the same thing to "ProductViewController", but it backs normally. WHat should i sending then? I am new in iOS, sorry for questioning like this. @chan

Comment: Yes i got it. I miss the difference. Its a silly thing. Thanks for commenting. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Try instead of
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 

Use
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Yes i got it. I miss the difference. Its a silly mistake. Thanks for commenting. :)